# Update Res Local value in different routes node js express

Tags: node.js, express, routes, router, local-variables

I'm new to node.js and express, and I'm having a hard time updating my response local values, I want to update `myVariable` later on other routes

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.myVariable = 'Initial Value';
  next();
});

const updateRoute = require('./routes/updateRoute');
const accessRoute = require('./routes/accessRoute');

app.use('/update', updateRoute);
app.use('/access', accessRoute);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

/updateRoute.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.locals.myVariable = 'Updated Value';
  res.send('Value updated.');
});

module.exports = router;
```

/accessRoute.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const message = res.locals.myVariable;
  res.send(`Value: ${message}`);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'd like to update the value of `myVariable` when calling GET request `/update`  so once calling GET request `/access` for instance, see the update value instead of the initial value. is there any quick solution?

Comment: According to the express documentation about [res.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals):

The variables set on res.locals are available within a single request-response cycle, and will not be shared between requests.

In order to keep local variables for use in template rendering between requests, use app.locals instead.